# Extract part of string in multiple places

Tags: sql-server

How can I extract part of this string

```
declare @string varchar(1024)
set @string = 'Total # of bytes             : 128270200832 (119.46GB)'
select Substring (@string, Charindex( ':', @string )+2 , Len(@string))
```

I only need the numbers after: and without the (119.46GB)

Answer (score 1):

Use `replace()` :

```
select replace(replace(Substring (@string, Charindex( ':', @string )+2 , Len(@string)), '(', ''), ')', '');
```

**EDIT** : If you don't want  values inside `()` then you can do :

```
select left(col, charindex('(', col) - 1) 
from ( values (Substring (@string, Charindex( ':', @string )+2 , Len(@string))) 
     ) t(col);
```

Comment: sorry if i wasn't clear.. i don't need this as well (119.46GB)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `STUFF` with `CHARINDEX` and a couple of replaces does the job:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(1024);
SET @string = 'Total # of bytes             : 128270200832 (119.46GB)';
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(STUFF(@string,1,CHARINDEX(':',@string)+1,''),'(',''),')','');
```

*Edit: Based on the new logic you have defined:*

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@String,V.CI,CHARINDEX('(',@String,V.CI) - V.CI)
FROM (VALUES(CHARINDEX(':',@string)+1))V(CI);
```

Comment: sorry if i wasn't clear.. i don't need this as well (119.46GB)

Comment: You just said "without the ()", @Avi . As you can see, this meant to both myself and Yogesh that you meant remove the `()` characters. You should update your question to be clear.

Comment: Are you saying the goal posts have moved again, @Avi ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @string varchar(1024)
set @string = 'Total # of bytes             : 128270200832 (119.46GB)'
select substring(@string,charindex(':',@string) + 2,(charindex('(',@string) - charindex(':',@string)-2))
```